# Migrate database from local to cloud with graph

Tags: icloud, cosmicmind

i would like to implement the cloud feature of graph.
I ve searched on cosmicmind site, on the github repo (looking for wiki), and through the issues (closed).
I have just learnt that feature is available, but i did not find any documentation.

Considering i am already using graph, in local:

```
let graph = Graph()
let entityPfx = "entityPfx"
let search = Search<Entity>(graph: graph).for(types: entityPfx)
let results = search.sync()
```

I would like users could retrieve data from the cloud in case of device upgrade or so.
Is there any documentation available in order to implement this?
Thank you.

Comment: There is not any documentation as of yet. It was removed when the the site was updated. That said, I can write an article for you if you make it an issue on GitHub. Then I will post it online.

Comment: I will open an issue right now then, thank you for the support!

Comment: @CosmicMind i have opened an issue as you requested, but there is no reply on the issue. May i ask if i just have to wait ? Thank you.

Comment: It has not been ignored, I have been away from my computer as I am away. I will take a look today, latest tomorrow.